# Circle through the circumcentre of a triangle problem

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles

Let ABC be an acute triangle and O it's circumcentre. Let S denote the circle through A,B, O. The lines CA and CB meet S again at P and Q, respectively.

Prove that the lines CO and PQ are perpendicular.

My initial idea was to construct the triangle so that the circumcentre was the origin of the 2d plane, and then use vector equation of the lines CO and PQ and the scalar product to show that they are perpendicular, however I haven't been able to find the vector equation of PQ and am really struggling.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not only that, but *O* is the orthocenter of triangle *CPQ*.

Comment: A cleaner approach is to take the center of S to be the origin.  Then without loss of generality you can scale such that $SA = SB = SO = 1$, and rotate such that $AB$ is horizontal.  Call the angle from the $X$ axis to $A$ $\theta$; $A = (\cos \theta,\sin\theta)$. Since $O$ is on the perpendicular bisector of $AB$, $O = (0,1)$.  Then draw the circumcircle, which has radius $r=\sqrt{\2-2\sin\theta}$. Let the angle of a horizontal thru $O$ to $C$ be $\phi$; then $C=r\cos\phi,1+r\sin\phi)$. Now the slopes of CA and CB are easy, and a bit of algebra gives you $P$ and $P$.Look at the slope of $PQ$.

Comment: Please don't deface your own post; once a question has an answer, it should not be changed dramatically.

Answer (score 2):

I will follow Lucian's hint and show that $O$ is the orthocentre of triangle $CPQ$.

[image]

It is enough to show that $PO$ is perpendicular to $CB$ and that $QO$ is perpendicular to $CA$. We will prove the first of these statements, and the other will follow by symmetry.

Since $OB = OA$, the arcs $OA$ and $OB$ are opposite. Hence by the inscribed angle theorem, the oriented angles $\angle OPA$ and $\angle OPB$ are opposite modulo $\pi$. (This is only true modulo $\pi$ because $P$ and $O$ could be on the same side of $AB$.)

Thus if $r$ is the reflection about line $PO$, the image of line $PB$ under $r$ is line $PA$. Since $PO$ is a diameter of circle $ABC$, the circle is invariant under $r$. Therefore $r(B)$ must belong both to circle $ABC$ and to line $PA$, hence $r(B)$ is either $A$ or $C$. It is easy to see that $r(B) \ne A$, since otherwise $PO$ would be a diameter of circle $OAB$ and, consequently, $PA$ would be tangent to circle $ABC$. Thus $r(B) = C$, which proves that $PO$ is perpendicular to $BC$.

Comment: And the reason it is sufficient to chow that $PO \perp CB$ and $QO \perp CA$ is that in triangle $BPC$, the altitude dropped from $C$ to $PB$ passes thru the intersection of the other two altitudes, which is $O$, and thus that altitude is the line $CO$.

Comment: @MarkFischler I think you mean $CPQ$. As I said in my answer, I prove that $O$ is the orthocentre of $CPQ$.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

1) Will the green marked angles equal to each other?

2) If yes, the red marked angle should be equal to each other. Right?

3) What is the size of $\angle QBC’$?

Comment: I can see why $\widehat A\equiv\widehat{C'},$ but I can't understand why $\widehat Q$ is congruent to either.

Comment: @ Lucian $\angle PQC$ is the exterior angle of the cyclic quadrilateral ABQP.

Comment: I can see now why $R\in\mathscr C(QBC'),$ but how do I prove that *QC’* is the diameter ?

Comment: @Lucian No. We don't prove QC' is the diameter. Instead, we find that COC' is the diameter of the circle CBC'A. $\angle CBC'$ happens to be on the semi-circle and is therefore $90^0$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let the intersection of $CO,PQ$ be $R$. Letting angles of the triangle be $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ find values of angles $RPC$ and $RCP$.